# This site cant be reached (ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED) javascript detection for window.open

Tags: javascript, http, https, cross-domain, protocols

I have this piece of javascript code doing my clickouts and it should enable correct click-out tracking. clickDestinations are all different, and there are many ( cross domain ).

```
var response = window.open(clickDestination, randomName);
if (typeof response.focus === 'function') {
      alert('tracking this click-out');
}
```

Problem with this implementation is the clickDestination was given by users and some of it is very old, so there is no guarantee that http or https protocol is correctly set.

When window.open is called with the wrong protocol, ex. with https on sites where https is not supported, i get "This site can’t be reached" page (**ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED**). But my tracker tracks anyway since var response is a window object.

Any ideas how can i detect the mistake and not track in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea valid if url is on the same domain (same origin policy applies here):

```
var w = window.open(url);

// if window opened successfully
if ( w ) {
    w.onload = function() {
        alert('tracking this click-out');
    };
}
```

Second idea:

> `window.open` returns a reference to the newly created window.
>   If the call failed, it will be `null` instead. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open).

So in case the connection fails because the server at specified URL does not support https or either http `null` will be returned so you can use this information to skip your tracking code.

Example (not tested):

```
var response = window.open(clickDestination, randomName);
// if destination cannot be open, skip tracking code
if(!response){
    return;
}
if (typeof response.focus === 'function') {
      alert('tracking this click-out');
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still a window object, i do get a new tab that says "This site can’t be reached", for example in Chrome. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Mccandless5 I have added another idea. I hope can be useful.

Comment: This answer explains everything that can be done in this case.